# OpenGL 3.3 vs 4.0 and Tessellation

Tags: opengl

From my understanding, modern OpenGL starts with version 3.3 which is mostly the same as 4.0. Both versions were released at the same time and 3.3 is just for back compatibility with older graphics cards. In my application I need to use tessellation control. All of the sources I have found online say tessellation starts with 4.0, but also say 3.3 is virtually the same.

Does OpenGL 3.3 have tessellation or not? Should I even bother with 3.3 in 2021 or should I just use the latest version 4.6? Is 4.6 compatible with mac?

Answer (score 0):

[Tessellation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation) shaders are in the standard since OpenGL 4.0. However you can test if you hardware supports the [ARB_tessellation_shader](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_tessellation_shader.txt) extension, which is written against the OpenGL 3.2.